# SPAMS. spams.lassoWeighted wrong outpt?

Tags: python, optimization, sparse-matrix, least-squares

Goodevening to everybody. I can not understand the output of the function Spams.lassoWeighted. If you run the example on their page 
http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/doc-python/html/doc_spams005.html#sec16:

```
import spams
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
print "test lasso weighted"
##############################################
# Decomposition of a large number of signals
##############################################
# data generation
X = np.asfortranarray(np.random.normal(size=(64,10000)))
X = np.asfortranarray(X / np.tile(np.sqrt((X*X).sum(axis=0)),(X.shape[0],1)),dtype= myfloat)
D = np.asfortranarray(np.random.normal(size=(64,256)))
D = np.asfortranarray(D / np.tile(np.sqrt((D*D).sum(axis=0)),(D.shape[0],1)),dtype= myfloat)
param = { 'L' : 20,
    'lambda1' : 0.15, 'numThreads' : 8, 'mode' : spams.PENALTY}
W = np.asfortranarray(np.random.random(size = (D.shape[1],X.shape[1])),dtype= myfloat)
tic = time.time()
alpha = spams.lassoWeighted(X,D,W,**param)
tac = time.time()
t = tac - tic
print "%f signals processed per second\n" %(float(X.shape[1]) / t)
```

you get as an output a matrix a 64x1, that contains only one non zero element. And thats the same for every case it gives every time only one non zero element per signal. I can not get it why the solution at ||x−Dα||2 + λ ||diag(w)α||1.  would be a with only one non zero element??

Answer (score 0):

The output matrix `alpha` has to have 10000 columns, since X is 64x10000 and 256 rows since the dictionary is 64x256 (since **Da=x**).  So `alpha` should be 256x10000.  Looking at the Inria Spams docs, the output for [LassoWeighted](http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/doc-python/html/doc_spams005.html#sec16) is:

```
Output:
   A: double sparse p x n matrix (output coefficients)
```

The parameter `lambda1` determines the number of non-zeros since it multiplies the l1 regularizer. Their implementation also has parameter `L` which is the maximum number of non-zeros per sparse vector.

So if I run the following:

```
import spams
import numpy as np
import time

np.random.seed(0)
print "test lasso weighted"
X = np.asfortranarray(np.random.normal(size=(64,10000)))
X = np.asfortranarray(X / np.tile(np.sqrt((X*X).sum(axis=0)),(X.shape[0],1)),dtype=float)
D = np.asfortranarray(np.random.normal(size=(64,256)))
D = np.asfortranarray(D / np.tile(np.sqrt((D*D).sum(axis=0)),(D.shape[0],1)),dtype=float)
param = { 'L' : 20,
    'lambda1' : 0.15, 'numThreads' : 8, 'mode' : spams.PENALTY}
W = np.asfortranarray(np.random.random(size = (D.shape[1],X.shape[1])),dtype=float)
tic = time.time()
alpha = spams.lassoWeighted(X,D,W,**param)
tac = time.time()
t = tac - tic
non_zero = []
for col in alpha.T:
    non_zero.append(col.nnz)
print 'Shape Output Matrix:', alpha.shape
print 'Min non-zeros of %d columns: %d'%(alpha.shape[1], np.min(non_zero)) 
print 'Max non-zeros of %d columns: %d'%(alpha.shape[1], np.max(non_zero)) 
print "%f signals processed per second\n" %(float(X.shape[1]) / t)
```

I get:

```
test lasso weighted
Shape Output Matrix: (256, 10000)
Min non-zeros of 10000 columns: 20
Max non-zeros of 10000 columns: 20
7691.130169 signals processed per second
```

So each of the 10000 sparse approximations, which are actually 256x1 vectors, has 20 non-zeros.

If we changed `params` to (maximum of 5 non-zeros):

```
param = { 'L' : 5,
    'lambda1' : 0.15, 'numThreads' : 8, 'mode' : spams.PENALTY}
```

Output:

```
test lasso weighted
Shape Output Matrix: (256, 10000)
Min non-zeros of 10000 columns: 5
Max non-zeros of 10000 columns: 5
26600.540090 signals processed per second
```

If you want denser sparse approximations (columns of alpha) you can make `L` bigger or get rid of it all together:

```
param = { 'lambda1' : 0.15, 'numThreads' : 8, 'mode' : spams.PENALTY}
```

Output:

```
test lasso weighted
Shape Output Matrix: (256, 10000)
Min non-zeros of 10000 columns: 40
Max non-zeros of 10000 columns: 61
1697.975321 signals processed per second
```